# How do you reset bash path variables?

Tags: bash, path

I have been trying to set `$CUDA_PATH` so that a package that I'm using is able to see it. I was receiving this error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA_PATH environment variable not set -
```

When I do

```
echo $CUDA_PATH
```

I get an empty return. Apparently, `CUDA_PATH` is set to be ~/ , which is not right.

I tried to `export PATH=$CUDA_PATH:"path_to_cuda"`. I immediately realised the mistake I made, and I was able to fix the `PATH` variable so that I can use basic commands like sudo, cd,ls etc. However

Now I am able to use bash commands everywhere except in locations like /etc. I can use cd but I can't use ls, vim, sudo, etc.

How shall I fix this properly? Also, since we are here, how do I set `CUDA_PATH` properly without messing with the other path variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `CUDA_PATH` separately, then add it to `PATH`:

```
export CUDA_PATH=/path/to/cuda
export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_PATH
```

If you need to reset `PATH` in your current shell, you can either exit the shell and start another one, or re-source your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved the CUDA_PATH issue. I was also able to solve the 
` /etc$ ls ` problem!